# Visio 2013: Set Image Size

Tags: images, microsoft-visio-2013

In Visio 2013, how do I explicitly set an image's height and width etc?

For example, in Word, you can right-click an image and select "Size and Position" and set absolute Height and Widths.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible via the context menu.

**Option 1:**

1. Click on the `View` menu
2. Click on the `Task Panes`
3. Click on the `Size & Position` Window
4. In the task-pane (usually bottom-left), type the new values in the Width, Height, or Length boxes.

[image]

You can select multiple shapes before doing this and it will size them all together.

**Option 2:**

You can also select the image and click on the Height/Width values in the Status Bar:
[image]